# Cannot check if the string is null or not

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, picasso

I am making an app in which I am receiving a JSON result from The Movie Database. This is my code to check whether I am receiving a null path or not. In former case, picasso simply assigns my ImageView with a drawable image.

```
String path = movieModels.get(position).getPosterPath();
Log.d("PATHOFIMAGES", path);
if(!android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty(path)) {
    Picasso.with(context).load("https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/" + path).into(holder.posterImage);
}
else {
    Log.d("PATHOFIMAGES", "ENTERED ELSE");
    Picasso.with(context).load(R.drawable.noimage).into(holder.posterImage);
}
```

But problem is this that my code is not going to else. When the result from the first Log.d is null, even then its is not going to else and no image is loaded. Log.d in the else block never logs anything no matter what the value of path is.
Can anyone help me in this?

P.S.: I've also checked `if (path != null && !path.isEmpty())` and it is also not working.

Comment: try **path.lenght() != 0**

Comment: I've included Log.d just for seeing the values of path and it is displaying the path link if it is available and `null` if it is null. So it doesn't affect the functionality of the if-else.

Comment: @MuhammedGÜNEŞ Still not working.

Comment: You can use Apache commons-lang , you could try `StringUtils.isEmpty(String str)` - Checks if a String is empty ("") or null.
or
`StringUtils.isBlank(String str)` - Checks if a String is whitespace, empty ("") or null.

Comment: it's so interesting.  Did you check **path** value on debug mode

Comment: Are you sure it's not a string called "null" ?

Comment: As you say the code isn't going to `else`,so how about `if` ?

Comment: The TextUtils works similar to StringUtils. See here [TextUtils](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html) @AmmarAkouri

Comment: No. It is returning `null` (`"poster_path":null`) @KenWolf

Comment: When I use `if(android.text.TextUtils.isEmpty(path))` keeping everything else same, then it is going to else.

Comment: @KenWolf has told you the answer. You can use `path.equals("null")` to check

Comment: Yes right @KenWolf. The JSON is returning null string and you have to check it as cole has mentioned

Answer (score 0):

The string will probably not be "null" but rather "".

So you can do something like:

```
if(!path.equals(""))
{
     //do stuff
}
```